# PHP:Stomp - Is it possible to catch errors on "send()"?

Tags: php, stomp

I'm using the [PHP Stomp client](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.stomp.php) to send a stomp message.

I would like to leave a persistent connection open, in the background, and send messages occasionally.

However, I can't find a way to handle connection errors if they happen after opening the connection (on send()).

For example, when running:

```
<?php
$stomp = new Stomp('tcp://localhost:61613');

sleep(5); // Connection goes down in the meantime

$result = $stomp->send('/topic/test', 'TEST');

print "send " . ($result ? "successful\n": "failed\n");
?>
```

Output: `send successful`

Even if the connection goes down while in `sleep()`, `send()` always returns true.

The [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.stomp.php) weren't very helpful, `Stomp::error()` and `stomp_connect_error()` also don't help much as they return `false`.

As a temporary solution, I'm reconnecting before every `send()`.

Is there a better way to catch connection errors?

Comment: Did you try giving a failover URL while instantiating Stomp? I think that will take care of reconnecting to the broker automatically.
And, did you try the stomp_connect_error() method? See this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stomp-connect-error.php

Comment: stomp_connect_error() doesn't work.   

didn't try it with failover url, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in the [specification](http://stomp.github.com/stomp-specification-1.1.html#Header_receipt) of the stomp protocol itself:

> Any client frame other than CONNECT MAY specify a receipt header with an arbitrary value. This will cause the server to acknowledge receipt of the frame with a RECEIPT frame which contains the value of this header as the value of the receipt-id header in the RECEIPT frame.

So setting a "receipt" header makes the request synchronous, so the connection to the server must be alive.

So the code:

```
$result = $stomp->send('/topic/test', 'TEST');
print "send " . ($result ? "successful\n": "failed\n");

$result = $stomp->send('/topic/test', 'TEST', array('receipt' => 'message-123'));
print "send " . ($result ? "successful\n": "failed\n");
```

Gives output:

```
send successful
send failed
```

It doesn't seem like the best solution for this case, but it works for me.

If anyone knows a better way I'll be happy to hear it.

---

**Update:**

Eventually I switched to [Stomp-PHP](http://stomp.fusesource.org/documentation/php/) (a pure PHP client) instead of the Pecl stomp client, which handles it [much better](http://stomp.fusesource.org/documentation/php/book.html#Synchronous_Operations).